# need to remove all but middle initial from email

Tags: regex

I have a huge list of emails that I need to find and replace an email that looks like this:

```
First.Middle.Last@gmail.com
```

to:

```
first.m.last@gmail.com
```

any help on how to do this? also can everything be lowercased in the output

Comment: In what environment are you executing this regular expression?

Comment: what language/tool are you using?

Comment: Are all of the addresses gmail ones that match that pattern, or are there other domains or other non-matching addresses as well?

Comment: @arshajii Im using sublime text editor

Comment: all domains are the same but I should add that some dont have a middle name and should be ignored

Comment: What do you mean when you say "List of emails" ? Every single answer here is wrong until you clarify.

Comment: Email's can't be parsed with simple regex. You should parse the email parts, then do your mods on the name part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find:

```
(\w+\.)(\w)\w*(\..*)
```

Replace with:

```
\L\1\2\3
```

Comment: Will this replace 'co' in something like fname.mname.sname@blah.co.uk or does this only match first instance?

Comment: @Srb1313711 I changed my regex.

Comment: I dont think this does anything

Comment: it just has to be a regular expression, I am using find and replace with sublime text 2

Comment: @BluGeni I slightly changed my regex. I tested it with SublimeText 2 and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Find What: `([^.]+)\.(.)[^.]*\.`
Replace with: `$1.\L$2.`

In perl:

```
my $str = 'First.Middle.Last@gmail.com';
$str =~ s/([^.]+)\.(.)[^.]*\./$1.\L$2./;
say $str;
```

**output:**

```
First.m.Last@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

And in JavaScript:

```
"First.Middle.Last@gmail.com".replace(/([^\.]+)\.(.{1})[^.]+\.(.+)/i, '$1.$2.$3').toLowerCase();
```

Will output:

```
first.m.last@gmail.com
```